# how to do routing in mvc , how to hide page extension name in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing, global-asax

I have website and I have a page called test.html page. When I browse http://www.domainName.com/test it shoul pick the test.html page without using a controller and action method.

what to i write in routeconfig.cs

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "",
                url: "",
                defaults: new
                {

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can achive it in two ways

In your routes configuration:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Yourhtmlroute","Yourcustomurl","Path/To/Your/test.html");
```

and

In your Controller:

```
return Redirect("YourCustomUrl");
```

Comment: if **"Path/To/Your/test.html"** is the html file path then what is **"Yourhtmlroute"** ?

Comment: http://localhost/smartpond/MyPage.html(working), but http://localhost/smartpond/MyPage not working
   routes.MapPageRoute("MyPage.html", "MyPage", "~/MyPage.html");

Comment: error- VirtualPath must be a non-empty string starting with ~/.
Parameter name: virtualPath

Comment: Just Add return Redirect("MyPage.html"); in your action method and place your html file in respective views folder, dont do any thing on routes configuration